# Multiple screen setup, applications startup on a single screen

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I'm on a triple monitor setup. I have some software that is supposed to startup with the system (Geary/Spotify/Franz) but it all starts on one of the screens only (not even the main one).

Is there a way to chose on which screen an application is supposed to launch? Assume I have this setup: 2 1 3 (each number is one monitor). I want to make it so that:

- Geary starts on the main monitor 1,
- Spotify starts on the secondary monitor 2,
- Franz starts on the tertiary monitor 3.

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04 (KDE gui), using a GTX1060 with proprietary Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [kde 19.04 remember window position](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=kde+19.04+remember+window+position) which may be in varying degrees of out of date:

1. Right-click the window
2. Click **Configure window behavior**
3. Select **Window-specific**
4. Click **New...**
5. click **Detect window properties** button at the bottom.
6. Select the window you want to configure.
7. When a window pops up, click **OK**.
8. In the **Geometry** tab, check **Size** and **Geometry**.
   !. Select **Remember** for each.

or

1. Right-click on the title-bar
2. Choosing **Advanced**
3. **Special Window Settings**

or

1. System Settings
2. Window Behaviour
3. Window Behaviour
4. Advanced